# PHP rename() Function: Literal Strings vs. Variables

Tags: php, html, string, variables, rename

I'm currently trying to have my website automatically move a file from the root directory where it is created into another folder to help with organization. I'm using the PHP rename() function and I can get it to work with literal strings but when I try using the variable name I get the error

> PHP Warning:  rename() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path,
>   resource given in...

My code works when I use,

```
$txt = "Additional Comments: ".$_POST['additionalComments']."\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);      
fclose($myfile);
rename('Leadership_Review2.txt', 'Leadership_Review/Leadership_Review2.txt');
```

However, when I use

```
$txt = "Additional Comments: ".$_POST['additionalComments']."\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);      
fclose($myfile);
$mydir = "Leadership_Review/";
rename($myfile, $mydir.$myfile);
```

I get the error mentioned above. It would be a lot more useful if I could use the variable name instead of having the literal string. Any help understanding rename or where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `$myfile` is a file (a closed one, at that), not a filename. You should pass to `rename` whatever you passed to `fopen` instead

Comment: Or, you could just `fopen` the correct destination path to begin with and forgo `rename` afterwards.

Comment: Which part of the error did you not understand?

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid and I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier. I'm still new to php. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP rename(oldpath,newpath) need full relative path of both "oldpath" and "newpath".
For Example,

```html
<?php 
$oldpath = "/public_html/images";
$newpath = "/public_html/pictures";

rename($oldpath,$newpath);
?>
```